# Add variable to existing string

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```
IF (@countryCode=="A") THEN
    @para1from = "America"
ELSEIF (@countryCode=="I") THEN
    @para1from = "India"
ENDIF

SET @paragraph1 = "I am from %%=(v(@para1from))=%%."
```

But when I send the email, its shown as "I am from %%=(v(@para1from))=%%."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve misplaced the v function name - try without the additional parentheses:

```
IF (@countryCode=="A") THEN
    @para1from = "America"
ELSEIF (@countryCode=="I") THEN
    @para1from = "India"
ENDIF

SET @paragraph1 = "I am from %%=v(@para1from)=%%."
```

Alternatively, you can use a concat function to get the same result:

```
IF (@countryCode=="A") THEN
    @para1from = "America"
ELSEIF (@countryCode=="I") THEN
    @para1from = "India"
ENDIF

SET @paragraph1 = Concat("I am from ", @para1from)
```

Comment: Using the v() Im now getting ""I am from %%=v(@para1from)=%%."" - I didnt try Concat as it's long string in production.

Comment: Try outputting using treatascontent: `%%=treatascontent(@paragraph1)=%%` or use the concat version

Comment: treatascontent worked ! Thanks again.